# Select for update vs update/insert (MySQL) Row Locking

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

So in InnoDB, MySQL locks the row if any of the two queries below are executed:

```
Select bal from table where id=1 for update
```

,

```
Update table set bal = 10 where id=1
```

But, in MySQL there are different types of row-locking:

- read-lock
- write-lock
- read and write lock

Are the types of row locking (r, w, r&w) the same for both queries?
i.e. Does the update query also lock the row from being read and written to?

Comment: Please remove the isolation-level tag, it is not relevant

Comment: Sorry, ill do it asap

Comment: Have you tried reading the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)? Your question is answered there as if written just for you: "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE: For index records the search encounters, locks the rows and any associated index entries, **the same as if you issued an UPDATE statement for those rows**. Other transactions are **blocked from updating those rows**, from doing SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE, or **from reading the data in certain transaction isolation levels**. Consistent reads ignore any locks set on the records that exist in the read view."

Comment: Is this a theoretical question?  Or do you have a context in which you are puzzling over a performance problem?  In the latter case, let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE(s)` and the transaction(s) involved.  Generally, you need to use certain locking in certain situations, and the locks are whatever they need to be.